# Winston rotate writing to mutiple files

Tags: javascript, node.js, winston

So Im using winston-daily-rotate-file.
In app.js I have:

```
var logger = require('./logger');
```

and then:

```
logger.info("logging to info");
logger.error("logging to error");
```

In logger/index.js I have:

```
var error_transport = new winston.transports.DailyRotateFile({
    filename: '../logs/error',
    datePattern: 'yyyy-MM-dd.',
    prepend: true,
    level: 'error',
name: 'error'
});
var info_transport = new winston.transports.DailyRotateFile({
    filename: '../logs/info',
    datePattern: 'yyyy-MM-dd.',
    prepend: true,
    level: 'info',
    name: 'info'
});

var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
        error_transport,
        info_transport
    ]
});

module.exports = logger;
```

What happens is that the file

```
logs/DATE_error
```

contains:

```
logging to error
```

BUT: the file

```
logs/DATE_info
```

contains:

```
logging to info
logging to error
```

Why is the info file also including logs from error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read about Winston's logging levels here: [Logging Levels](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#logging-levels)

The basic reason that info is including logs from error is that "levels" with a higher priority number will always log messages for any level "below" them in priority. See the example under [Using Logging Levels](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#using-logging-levels)

```html
  var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
      new (winston.transports.Console)({ level: 'warn' }),
      new (winston.transports.File)({ filename: 'somefile.log', level: 'error' })
    ]
  });
  logger.debug("Will not be logged in either transport!");
  logger.transports.console.level = 'debug';
  logger.transports.file.level = 'verbose';
  logger.verbose("Will be logged in both transports!");
```

Comment: I read a little bit there. But couldn't find it. Is it possibile to only write errors to errorlog and infos to infologs?

Comment: The easiest way I can think of to do that is to make 2 loggers. One for errors and one for info.